# In python should a function change a list or make a copy and return that?

Tags: python, list, function, standards

I am making a function to perform the midpoint displacement algorithm, as well as some other realistic looking terrain generation functions, on a 2d list (of format [[n11,n12,...],[n11,n12,...],...])

My question is, in python, is it standard to change the input list in such a case (with no return value) or is it better to make a deep copy of the list and return it?

I know copy and return is less efficient, however I don't want use of the function to be confusing to others.

Comment: Whichever way you go, make sure your function name makes it as clear as possible what it is doing (returning a new list or modifying the input list).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a chain of function decorators in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I did it as the first approach, because many of my application is efficiency-critical.

If necessarily, my solution is to set a flag, and do in different manners according to the flag. For example, the function would be :

```
def func(input, deepcopy=false):
    if deepcopy:
        // deep copy the input as to_process
    else:
        // just point to_process to the input
    // process with the to_process
```

Comment: This caters to the possibility that someone might pass a list *slice* as input, in which case a copy must be returned.

Comment: @chepner Sure, the function only works when it is possible. In the specific case, you mentioned, we can not do that.

Comment: @chepner, your comment helped me learn something.  I would have never expected that a slice would not be treated the same way as a list since a slice is of `<type 'list'>`.  After looking further I have found that you can pass a list and a slice object and can then modify the slice in place.

Comment: The problem with passing a slice is that the slice is an `list` object whose  only reference is the parameter name in the function. Once the function returns, that reference goes out of scope and the reference count on the slice goes to 0. You simply have no function-external way of seeing the result of modifying the slice.

Answer (score 2):

This is something I'm thinking about a lot, too. Second approach is probably cleaner and better because clients don't need to assume anything about your function and it's not confusing. Me personally, I would prefer that. Whenever I call a function, I'd like for it to return a new value with the old unchanged. But, that is just me.